# Create a spatial weight matrix but without shp file

Tags: r, spatial

I have a data about municipalities in France. And I want to create a spatial weight matrix using this data. But the problem is this is not a `.shp` file data. It is `.csv` Below is the link to the [data file](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/r/44fae2d6-5b0f-4cc2-97a5-9058296f6ce6). This file has more than 35000 municipalities. For simplicity, I will just assume that there are only 10 municipalities. So the data will be of the form:-

```
data <- data.frame(insee=c("01001", "01002", "01004", "01005", "01006"),
                  insee_voisins=c("01002|01004|01005", "01001|01005", "01001|01006",
                                  "01001|01002|01006", "01004|01006"))
```

Assuming that the above data creates a proper spatial pattern, how make its spatial weights matrix which will be of the following form:-

```
       [, 1]  [, 2]  [, 3]  [, 4]  [, 5]
[1, ]    0      1      1      1      0
[2, ]    1      0      0      1      0
[3, ]    1      0      0      0      1
[4, ]    1      1      0      0      1
[5, ]    0      0      1      1      0
```

Please keep in mind that the actual data has more than 35000 municipalities. So if you have a memory and speed efficient solution, it would be better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want `splitstackshape::cSplit_e(data, "insee_voisins", sep = '|', fill = 0)` ?

Comment: Yes, this is good on the small data, but on the bigger data it does not works. It gives the error "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 25.8 Gb".